# Cannot create asynchronous query: while adding change listener to results

Tags: android, realm

I get this error:

```
IllegalStateException: Cannot create asynchronous query while in a write transaction
```

Error is init from here:

```
        mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                results = realm.where(Data.class).findAll();
                results.addChangeListener(listener);
            }
        });
```

Is there some safe way to do what I'm doing, making sure that I dont run into "realm is still in write transaction state" AND "Cannot create asynchronous query while in a write transaction" is avoided while I add change listener to my results?

From Pandas comment:

```
results = realm.where(Data.class).findAll();
if (realm is not in transaction right now) {
     results.addChangeListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to run a transaction just to read data. And if you *are* in a transaction, don't use `addChangeListener`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Hi. I updated post. I did not know that I dont need to run transaction if I'm reading data - thanks for information. Also, is there a way to check if "there's already a transaction happening"?

Comment: `if(!realm.isInTransaction()) {` but technically you shouldn't even need to add change listeners while inside a transaction, or you shouldn't be in a transaction just to start reading, stuff like that